# How to add new Custom option in between other Option

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, custom-options

I have added the "custom option"(Programmatically) with Configurable product`s option on cart page.But all the custom option are coming under the configurable product`s option. So what i need is that add custom option between the Configurable product `s Option. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: please give an screenshot

Comment: @AmitBera I have added the screenshot

Comment: is metal option exits to all products? '

Comment: Yes ,metal is configurable product options and it will available to all product

Comment: It is not complex  to do.,You need an array work for this works. First take all option it label to array then sort them.